# How can I (automatically) check for new mail in Wanderlust?

Tags: email, wanderlust, imap

Wanderlust doesn't update the number of new/unread/total mails in the "Folder" view. I have configured it to use my dovecot imap server and I didn't find any way to configure an update interval or even a keybinding or a function to update this information. Currently, the only way is to press "RET" on a folder to update it. With some 30 folders, this is of course not the way to go.

Surely, there has to be some most simple way to do it, but I'm too dumb to find it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure `wl-biff-check-folder-list` and the function `wl` will activate `wl-biff-start` when launching Wanderlust.  There are other variables that begin with `wl-biff-...` that the original poster may wish to customize.

To read where this configuration takes place, type:  `M-x find-function RET wl RET` (after the `wl` library has been loaded, of course).  The relevant code snippet is:

```lisp
(when wl-biff-check-folder-list
  (unless arg (wl-biff-check-folders))
  (wl-biff-start))
```

NOTE: @lawlist doesn't use this because there were some issues with `Blocking call to accept-process-output with quit inhibited!!`. See:  https://github.com/wanderlust/wanderlust/issues/38  @lawlist also does not keep Wanderlust connected all the time -- after an operation, @lawlist chooses to turn the plug off `(wl-toggle-plugged 'off)`. Perhaps the original poster will have better luck with checking email on a timer.  Alternatives include, but are not limited to:  keeping a cell phone with email notification on the desk, and/or put an email notifier in the menu-bar of the OS. :)